# Difference between nginx ldap auth & CoreOS Dex

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, tectonic-coreos

I am trying to put some kind of authenticator in front of my kubernetes applications. I have been using the nginx-ldap-auth image with the traditional applications on docker containers.
But when on kubernetes and exposing applications on NodePort Services, what is the best way to put authentication around it?

Dex seems to be authentication solution for kubernetes as a whole, but does it also help in authenticating web UIservices hosted on Kubernetes?

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes provides a few fundamental [Authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#authentication-strategies) concepts that actually manage *access-control* function. [OpenID Connect](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#openid-connect-tokens) as a part of authentication model represents a flexible way how to handle token ID based verification for user identity through a variety of *Identity Provider software's* protocols like [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/), however K8s doesn't provide any OpenID Identity Provider in front of the cluster.

[Dex](https://github.com/dexidp/dex/blob/master/Documentation/kubernetes.md) as OpenID service can be used for authentication purposes to Kubernetes API server through *OpenID K8s authentication [plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#configuring-the-api-server)*, however hosted in Kubernetes web application needs to be supplied with any of OAuth2 client in order to determine user identity and obtain Token ID as described [here](https://github.com/dexidp/dex/blob/master/Documentation/using-dex.md).

Assuming that you have exposed web application running on K8s cluster, [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource might extend L7 network features for the target application service, like Load balancing, SSL/TLS termination, network traffic routing, etc.; for that purpose [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) has to be implemented in K8s cluster, thus all HTTP/HTTPS requests will be routed and processed according to specified rules inside Ingress object.

Go further, and searching for [NGINX](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) *Ingress Controller*, gives you an opportunity to adjust or extend some significant functionality of typical Ingress Controller via [Annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#annotations) and apply i.e. [oauth2_proxy](https://github.com/pusher/oauth2_proxy) as external authentication provider to handle user request identification on Ingress object, as described in Kubernetes dashboard [example](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth).

By the way, `nginx-ldap-auth` module seems to be compatible with *NGINX Ingress Controller* as well, hence you can check it [tiagoapimenta/nginx-ldap-auth](https://github.com/tiagoapimenta/nginx-ldap-auth).

Answer (score 2):

I have used [authelia](https://github.com/clems4ever/authelia) for protecting ingress resources, it worked very well. After setting up and configuring authelia, all you have to do is add a couple of annotations to your ingress objects.

See example here: https://github.com/clems4ever/authelia/blob/v4.0.0-alpha1/example/kube/apps/apps.yml#L78-L79

You can define pretty complex rules for your ingress domains.